# Set Flink Detached Mode using Java

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

Flink Cluster Details,
**Number of nodes** : 4 
**Flink Version** : 1.11 
**Flink Client** : RestCluserClient

We are submitting Flink batch job from streaming job using PackagedProgram, but our requirement is to execute only one job at a time, let's say we got 2 events from source so idealy 2 batch job must be triggered(each per event) but only one at a time. To achieve this, we were using **client.setDetached(false)** (in previous version of flink), but once we have migrated it to 1.11 setDetached(false) API has been removed.

Do we have any idea how to implement this requirement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysis more on this, I found the solution.
Flink 1.11 API provided Utils class for submitting the job viz,**ClientUtils** and it has two methods,

1. **ClientUtils.submitJob()** -> this method works with detached mode as true
2. **ClientUtils.submitJobAndWaitForExecutionResult()** -> this works as detached mode as false.